# How can I get this script to output the distinguished name?

Tags: powershell

I've added what I thought the distinguished name should be 'dn' but it comes back blank. The givenname and sn fields are returned OK.

Thanks.

```
$Dom = 'LDAP://DC=oakland;DC=local'
$Root = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry $Dom
$i=0
$selector = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$selector.SearchRoot = $root

$adobj= $selector.findall() | where {$_.properties.objectcategory -match "CN=Person"}

foreach ($person in $adobj){
    $prop=$person.properties
    $i++
    Write-Host "$($prop.givenname) $($prop.sn) $($prop.dn)" 
}

"Total $i"
```

Comment: id `$prop.distinguishedname` what you need?

Comment: That or $prop.Item("distinguishedname")

Comment: Yes it is thanks. How do I actually mark this as answered? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `$prop.distinguishedname`.